# How to replace all the tabs in each file in a file system branch with 2 spaces each?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I code Scala and it's convention is to use double spaces per level for identiation. But using different editors makes my sources filled with a mix of spaces and tabs.

I'd like to refactor all the files (*.scala files, actually, but specifying this is not necessary) (in a given directory and all the underlying FS branch (recursively)) automatically, replacing all the tabs with double spaces. I believe there is an easy and beautiful way to do this with classic Unix/GNU tools, but I lack any experience in this area. Would you be so kind to help me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Recursively, using `expand` (which was made for this purpose): `find . -type f -name '*.scala' -exec bash -c 'for x in "$@"; do mv "$x"{,.bak} && expand -t 2 "$x.bak" > "$x" && rm "$x.bak"; done' {} +`

I would do it with `sed` or `perl` (see Sardathrion's answer) because they support inline editing, but I wanted to mention good ol' `expand` anyway.

EDIT: That would be `find . -type f -name '*.scala' -exec perl -p -i -e $'s/\t/  /g' {} +`

Comment: The first variant works as expected. The second (perl) variant replaces a tab with only one space instead of two.

Comment: Yeah, sorry: that was a formatting mistake. The source code says two spaces, but the rendered HTML only shows one.

Answer (score 10):

This should do it:

```
find . -type f -name '*.scala$' -exec sed -i 's/\t/  /g' {} +
```

Note: *this is not tested.*

Comment: This is not yet recursive. You can use `find` or a shell that supports `**/*.scala` for recursion.

Comment: Edited to add recursive behaviour...

Comment: Please do not promote `find | xargs`. Use `find -exec` instead, like I mentioned in my answer. Easier and safer.

Comment: Tried this, no result. The command returns immediately and nothing changes inside the files.

Comment: *this is not tested* but the gist of it will work.